# How to execute command using python?

Tags: python

I am using a command to invoke an application, which opens application a new command window which can be done using subprocess in python.

Is there a way to execute some commands in that new window in python ?

Comment: Include the command you use and the command you want to execute please.

Comment: @Raffa `nbjob run some_application` will open the application command window with some jobID now I want to run some more command in that application command window thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

The way to open a terminal emulator, run some commands and then have it display the command prompt would be to supply these commands followed by a command that invokes the shell on the command line for invoking the terminal. Since a command line for a terminal allows for launching a single program, you can work either with a script, or with a command that invokes a shell to run the commands. Such shell can be python:

For example:

```
gnome-terminal -- sh -c "python -c 'print(1+1)' && python"
```